# Need help to get records from more than 2 tables in given date

Tags: sql-server

Please help me to write optimize query for to fulfill my requirement. My scenario is as follows.

I want data from 4 tables:

1. user
2. product
3. transaction
4. transaction history

There are two main types of transaction

1. Add

   - New
   - Old
2. Remove & And this also has sub types

   - New
   - Old

I want to fetch all transaction record per product and add one more column `member_type` (Titanium/Gold/Silver) in result set based on first transaction amount.

Below are tables structure:

User

```
user_id   f_name    l_name
  1        A          B 
  2        C          D
```

Product

```
 p_id     name 
  1        P1
  2        P2
```

Transaction

```
t_id     user_id   main_trans_type    sub_trans_type   date 
1         1          Add                 New          2016-04-13 10:24:56.683
2         1          Add                 Old          2016-04-14 16:24:56.683
3         1          Remove              New          2016-04-15 12:24:56.683
4         1          Add                 old          2016-04-16 13:24:56.683
5         2          Add                 new          2016-04-20 17:24:56.683
```

Transaction history

```
h_id      trans_id     product_id       amount
1           1             1              1000
2           1             2              5000
3           2             1              8000
4           2             2              40000
5           5             1              6000
6           5             2              30000
```

Need Output as below:

- If first new transaction amount > 5000 then Titanium
- If first new transaction amount > 2000 & amount <5000 then Gold
- In transaction date (where date between 2016-04-13, 2016-04-14)

Output

```
user_id   name  product_id   product_name  amount  main_trans_type    sub_trans_type   membership     date 
 1       A B     1           P1            1000      Add                 new            Silver     2016-04-13 10:24:56.683
 1       A B     2           P2            5000      Add                 new            Titanium   2016-04-13 10:24:56.683
 1       A B     2           P1            8000      Add                 Old            Silver     2016-04-14 16:24:56.683
 1       A B     2           P2            40000     Add                 Old            Titanium   2016-04-14 16:24:56.683
```

For all transactions done.

Comment: don't like writing this... but, what have you actually tried? If you show your efforts, we can guide you on what you're doing wrong. Otherwise we're spoon feeding you an answer and doing all the work for you. You will learn very little this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` will do things for you. Because you don't provide full cases for naming membership I show you an example (look in `CASE WHEN` statement)

```
SELECT  u.[user_id] ,
        u.f_name + ' ' + u.l_name as name,
        th.product_id,
        p.name as product_name,
        th.amount,
        t.main_trans_type,
        t.sub_trans_type,
        CASE WHEN th.amount > 5000 THEN 'Titanium'
             WHEN th.amount between 2000 and 5000 THEN 'Gold'
             ELSE 'Silver' END as membership,
        t.[date]
FROM [User] u
INNER JOIN [Transaction] t
    ON t.[user_id] = u.[user_id]
INNER JOIN [TransactionHistory] th
    ON t.t_id = th.trans_id
INNER JOIN [Product] p
    ON th.product_id = p.p_id
WHERE CAST(t.[date] as date) between '2016-04-13' and '2016-04-14'
```

Output:

```
user_id name    product_id  product_name    amount  main_trans_type sub_trans_type  membership  date
1       A B     1           P1              1000    Add             New             Silver      2016-04-13 10:24:56.683
1       A B     2           P2              5000    Add             New             Gold        2016-04-13 10:24:56.683
1       A B     1           P1              8000    Add             Old             Titanium    2016-04-14 16:24:56.683
1       A B     2           P2              40000   Add             Old             Titanium    2016-04-14 16:24:56.683
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @User TABLE 
    ( user_id  int,  f_name  varchar(1),  l_name  varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO @User
    ( user_id ,  f_name ,  l_name )
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 'B'),
    (2, 'C', 'D')
;



DECLARE  @Product TABLE 
    ( p_id  int,  name  varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO @Product
    ( p_id ,  name )
VALUES
    (1, 'P1'),
    (2, 'P2')
;



DECLARE @Transaction TABLE 
    ( t_id  int,  user_id  int,  main_trans_type  varchar(6),  sub_trans_type  varchar(3),  date  varchar(23))
;

INSERT INTO @Transaction
    ( t_id ,  user_id ,  main_trans_type ,  sub_trans_type ,  date )
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Add', 'New', '2016-04-13 10:24:56.683'),
    (2, 1, 'Add', 'Old', '2016-04-14 16:24:56.683'),
    (3, 1, 'Remove', 'New', '2016-04-15 12:24:56.683'),
    (4, 1, 'Add', 'old', '2016-04-16 13:24:56.683'),
    (5, 2, 'Add', 'new', '2016-04-20 17:24:56.683')
;



Declare @transactionhistory TABLE 
    ( h_id  int,  trans_id  int,  product_id  int,  amount  int)
;

INSERT INTO @transactionhistory
    ( h_id ,  trans_id ,  product_id ,  amount )
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 1000),
    (2, 1, 2, 5000),
    (3, 2, 1, 8000),
    (4, 2, 2, 40000),
    (5, 5, 1, 6000),
    (6, 5, 2, 30000)
;
```

Here is the Solution

```
select u.user_id,
u.f_name+u.l_name,
p.p_id,
P.name,
th.amount,
T.main_trans_type,
T.sub_trans_type,
CASE WHEN th.amount > 5000 then 'Titanium'
WHEN th.amount > 2000 and th.amount < 5000 then 'Gold'
WHEN t.date between '2016-04-13 10:24:56.683' and '2016-04-14 16:24:56.683' then 'Silver' END Membership,
T.date from @User u
INNER JOIN @Product P
ON U.user_id = P.p_id
INNER JOIN @Transaction T
ON U.user_id = T.user_id
INNER JOIN @transactionhistory th
    ON t.t_id= Th.trans_id WHERE  u.f_name <> 'C'
ORDER BY th.amount
```

Comment: @amrut mostly satisfies your requirement

Comment: Please separate the initialization code from the SELECT itself, and format the SELECT statement. The actual solution is lost due to scrolling

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @PanagiotisKanavos I have modified

Answer (score 1):

to extend @mohan111's answer you can add an outer apply to get the first new transaction amount for each product brought by the customer and can use in case when to decide the membership type.

```
SELECT u.user_id,
    u.f_name+u.l_name,
    p.p_id,
    P.name,
    th.amount,
    T.main_trans_type,
    T.sub_trans_type,
    CASE    WHEN mt.amount > 5000 THEN 'Titanium'
            WHEN mt.amount > 2000 AND mt.amount <= 5000 THEN 'Gold' 
            ELSE 'Silver' 
    END Membership, 
    mt.amount,
    T.date 
FROM @User u
INNER JOIN @Product P ON U.user_id = P.p_id
INNER JOIN @Transaction T ON U.user_id = T.user_id
INNER JOIN @transactionhistory th ON t.t_id= Th.trans_id 
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 th1.amount 
            FROM @transactionhistory th1 
            inner join @Transaction t1 ON t1.t_id = th1.trans_id
                AND t1.sub_trans_type = 'new' 
                AND t1.user_id = t.user_id
                AND th1.product_id = th.product_id
            ORDER BY th1.h_id
        ) AS mt
WHERE  u.f_name <> 'C' 
AND t.date between '2016-04-13' and '2016-04-14 23:59:59.970'
```